# Binding Listview Item Count to Label Visibility in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with binding in Xamarin Forms. I want to set `IsVisible` property of `Label` to `true/false` according of count items of `Listview`. If `Listview` have any items, `Label IsVisible` will be `false`, otherwise will be `true`. Is it possible to make in Xamarin Forms with binding? I tried to do this but I don't know how to convert number `0` to `boolean false` in XAML.

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far? On XAML and code behind

Answer (score 11):

You can do it purely in XAML using a [DataTrigger](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/#Data_Triggers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ListViewTriggerToHideLabel.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" IsVisible="False">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                             Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference TheListView}, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" 
                             Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
        <ListView x:Name="TheListView" />
        <Button Text="Add an item" Clicked="Button_OnClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The code-behind to handle button clicks and initialise the list content (I normally use [data binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/), but for simplicity in the example I'm using code-behind):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ListViewTriggerToHideLabel {
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage() {
      InitializeComponent();
      TheListView.ItemsSource = _items;
    }

    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      _items.Add("Ouch");
    }
  }
}
```

The binding to the [Count](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection%3CT%3E.Count/) property works because the [ItemsSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/) is an [ObservableCollection](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/).

Answer (score 4):

It certainly is possible. I assume that you already have a way of getting the count of the items in the ListView so here's how to convert that number to a boolean value in XAML.

What you need, is a custom implementation of the [IValueConverter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/) interface. It can take a value provided by the binding and convert it to something else and back if needed.

In your case, you want to take an integer and return a boolean. If the value is zero, you'll return true and otherwise false.

```cs
public class CountToBoolenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return (int)value != 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

Next, you'll need to define the namespace in the XAML. On top of the file you should add something like this:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace;assembly=YourAssembly"
```

Add the converter to the page resources just after the opening `<ContentPage>` tag (or whatever type of page you have):

```xml
<ContentPage>
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <CountToBoolenConverter x:Key="countToBoolean" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <!-- Rest of the page -->
```

And then finally use the converter to set the IsVisible property to your Label:

```xml
<Label IsVisible="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource countToBoolean}}">
```

ItemCount is an integer property in your viewmodel and it should contain the count of the ListView items. You probably already have a way of loading a collection of items for the ListView so it should be trivial to figure out how this property should be done.

Comment: @vamteusz No problem! Feel free to mark it as an answer if that solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XAML

```
   <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabel}">
        </Label>
        <ListView x:Name="TheListView" />

        <Button x:Name="btnAddItem" Text="Add an item" Clicked="btnAddItem_Clicked"   />
    </StackLayout>



 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public bool ShowLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return !(Items.Count > 0);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }

        set
        {
            _items = value;

        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        TheListView.ItemsSource = _items;
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void btnAddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add("Add a item");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowLabel");            
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }}
```